# DragControls with three.js module is not working on Node.js and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, three.js, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drag and drop objects to change their positions with Three.js in React. I tried to use `three-dragcontrols` and `drag-controls` Node modules but the dragging functionality that's brought by those modules are not working. Here's my implementation:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

// DragControls.install({ THREE: THREE }); // for 'drag-controls' module only

const rendererGl = buildRendererGl();
const objects = [];

function buildRendererGl() {
  const rendererGl = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas // canvas is an appended child HTML element of a DOM element
  });
  rendererGl.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

  rendererGl.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  rendererGl.domElement.style.top = 0;

  return rendererGl;
}

// ... a lot more including rendererGl.setSize(width, height) upon window.onresize
// and rendererGl.render(sceneGl, camera) upon update

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(40, 40, 40);
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const object = new THREE.Mesh(
    geometry,
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: Math.random() * 0xffffff })
  );
  object.position.x = Math.random() * 1000 - 500;
  object.position.y = Math.random() * 600 - 300;
  object.position.z = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
  object.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
  object.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
  object.rotation.z = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
  object.scale.x = Math.random() * 2 + 1;
  object.scale.y = Math.random() * 2 + 1;
  object.scale.z = Math.random() * 2 + 1;
  sceneGl.add(object);
  objects.push(object);
}

const dragControls = new DragControls( objects, sceneGl, rendererGl.domElement );
dragControls.addEventListener('dragstart', function() {
  controls.enabled = false;
});
dragControls.addEventListener('dragend', function() {
  controls.enabled = true;
});
```

The result is like, everything is working well but can't drag any draggable objects.

I'm also using `import { CSS3DRenderer } from 'three-css3drenderer'` that has its own DOM element and `import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'` but I don't think they're hindering the drag functionality because the `THREE.Raycaster()` that I've implemented to change a mesh color upon hovering is working well. Here's my `rendererCss`:

```
const rendererCss = buildRendererCss(containerElement);

function buildRendererCss(domElement) {
  const rendererCss = new CSS3DRenderer();

  rendererCss.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  rendererCss.domElement.style.top = 0;
  domElement.appendChild(rendererCss.domElement);

  return rendererCss;
}

// ... and rendererCss.render(sceneCss, camera) upon update
```

Does anybody know how can I implement `DragControls` on Node.js, specially in React v16.8.4 *(or higher)* with three 0.102.1 *(or higher)*? What did you do to make them work? Any alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inputing a `THREE.Scene` instead of a `THREE.Camera` on the second argument of `DragControls` is a wrap, with the help of @jbyte: https://github.com/jbyte/three-dragcontrols/issues/2#issuecomment-480594826

And I've figure out that there's a problem  when you use `DragControls` and `CSS3DRenderer` at the same time:

- https://github.com/jbyte/three-dragcontrols/issues/2#issuecomment-480602491
- https://discourse.threejs.org/t/dragcontrols-with-css3drenderer/783?u=5ervant